# C, Bad access error, ¿por qué?

Tags: c

estoy haciendo en C una copia de la función memset, y a la hora de ejecutar me salta la siguiente excepción, y no entiendo donde está el error:

```
#include "libft.h"

void    *ft_memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)
{
    size_t  idx;
    
    idx = 0;
    while (idx < n)
    {
        *((unsigned char *)s + idx) = c;
        idx = idx+1;
    }
    return (s);
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str = "Esto es una prueba";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    ft_memset(str, '$', 3);
    printf("%s\n", str); 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en que no puedes modificar un literal de texto. La variable `str` apunta a memoria estática (a la memoria de un literal de texto).

[Prueba esto](https://tio.run/##dU9BTsMwEDzbr1gFUO3UoALHlN54BaAq2JvGUuNUXrsgUN8e1qECcWAPq53RzGjWXu@snaYLH@w@O4Q1JefHm34j/1AOu8LJ4@gd1F3aDjgQJvWNyYAPCawB8h@4TRC0/JTiDMC790YCjxR8wgOsGineer9HUIVYF71gg6iVyoH8LqAD27cRak2wLAGabZZt5wTey1uGJylFxJRjAEW6kYxLk6H1Ye4295iTKMWnu9ULe6tHSiMgQQ4tHGLG17biqENkZ6eqK3oOlSl6zhO/rzJhYHG5MHCv/5P/lOEPT9P0BQ):

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[20] = "Esto es una prueba";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    ft_memset(str, '$', 3);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

En este caso `str` apunta a una formación de caracteres que se ha inicializado con un literal de texto, por lo que su memoria no es estática.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, muchas gracias!!